# Random Vector Manipulation

Tags: c++11, vector, mfc

I would like to use MFC with a combination of std::remove/remove_if with std:erase to manipulate a vector of `<std::shared_ptr<CString> >` containing a list of file names from a recursively searched root. Imagine the following:

A dialog box containing:

- two radio buttons (Keep and Delete)
- a number of check boxes with image file
  extensions as labels (JPG, TIF, GIF, etc.)
- a button to do the action

If I select Keep, I want to keep all the files with the checked extensions and delete everything else or delete them directly if I select Delete. As an example, I thought I could use something similar to

```
void CPicsDlg::FilterFiles(void)
{
    auto end = std::remove_if(g_vFiles.begin(), g_vFiles.end(), [&](std::shared_ptr<CString> const &strFile) { return strFile->Right(3) == "JPG" || strFile->Right(3) == "TIF" });

    g_vFiles.erase(end, g_vFiles.end());
}
```

if I wanted to keep or delete files with just those 2 extensions. But I'll never know which checkboxes are selected, so I'm not sure how to build my condition and I think if I try to use remove_if for one at a time, then files I want to keep or delete in addition to the first one will already be removed from the vector! I don't think remove can be used because it wants a specific value and obviously all the files and paths will be unique. I probably could iterate through the vector and keep or delete each one that meets my condition at that index, but that seems like overkill. So how do I go about accomplishing this?

I hope this makes sense and if something similar has been covered elsewhere, please direct me there. TIA

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the uestion correct it is just a simple XOR

```
Keep Match ToDelete
0    0     0
0    1     1
1    0     1
1    1     0
```

The code is

```
bool bKeep = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_KEEP)!=0;
bool bTypeJPG = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_JPG)!=0;
bool bTypeTIF = IsDlgButtonChecked(IDC_TIF)!=0;
...
auto end = std::remove_if(g_vFiles.begin(), g_vFiles.end(), 
    [&](std::shared_ptr<CString> const &strFile) 
    { 
        return bKeep ^
               ((bTypeJPG && strFile->Right(4)==".JPG") ||
                (bTypeTIF && strFile->Right(4)==".TIF") ||
                (bType... && strFile->Right(4)=="...."))
    }
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was exactly what I needed. If I used XOR more, I might've come up with this on my own! :) Could this can be adapted if the checkboxes and extensions are created programmatically because the total amount is unknown?